# Mercurial: Merging a Closed Head into Another Branch

Tags: merge, mercurial

If I close a branch and then merge the closed head into another branch does that merge bring any changes with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. "Closing" a branch doesn't invalidate its changesets, it just tells mercurial that you don't plan to continue committing to it (and therefore you don't want to see it in certain contexts). Merging it will apply all changes since the common ancestor of the two merge parents, as usual.